# HNN decomposition of finite rank free group over infinite rank subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

It's a nice result of Swarup that whenever a free group $G$ splits as an HNN extension $G = J \ast_{H,t}$ with $H$ a finitely generated subgroup, there exist splittings $J = J_1 \ast J_2$ and $H = H_1 \ast H_2$ such that $H_1 \neq 1$ is a free factor of $J_1$.

I would like to know if there exists an analogous result in the literature in the case when $G$ is a finite rank free group which admits an HNN splitting $G = J \ast_H$, where $J$ and $H$ are *infinite rank* free groups? Or conversely if there's an obvious counter-example to such a result.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't quite given the full strength of Swarup's result, which is what makes it so useful: moreover, $H_2$ and $tHt^{-1}$ are conjugate into $J_2$. The geometric interpretation is that a natural square-complex realisation of $G$ has a free face.

There is no analogous result of the full statement of Swarup's theorem when the edge and vertex groups are of infinite rank. For example, take $G=\langle a,t\rangle$ and consider the retraction to $\mathbb{Z}=\langle t\rangle$ given by killing $a$. This gives us the semidirect product decomposition

$G=J\rtimes \mathbb{Z}$

where $J$ is free on $\{t^nat^{-n}\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. We can think of this as an HNN decomposition with vertex and *both* edge groups equal to $J$. Thus, we can't have one of the edge groups conjugate into a proper free factor of $J$, so the analogue of Swarup's theorem doesn't hold.

However, off the top of my head, I don't know if your weaker version of Swarup might work in the infinite rank case.  (Note: In an earlier version I said it didn't, but I had misinterpreted what you wrote slightly. Apologies!)

By the way, there are many modern generalisations of Swarup's theorem. You might be interested in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0510198) paper of Diao and Feighn, which explains the square-complex point of view.

Answer (score 3):

The situation with infinite rank edge and vertex groups is qualitatively very different. For example, the following paper by Hagen and Wise shows that a non-trivial class of hyperbolic groups (constructible groups) are virtually HNN extensions of (infinite rank) free groups [Special groups with an elementary hierarchy are virtually free-by-ℤ](https://ems.press/journals/ggd/articles/4164).

On a technical note, in Swarup's original paper, the paper by Diao and Feighn mentionned in another answer, and my own paper [On the one-endedness of graphs of groups](https://msp.org/pjm/2015/278-2/p08.xhtml) which is inspired by Diao-Feighn, finite generation of the edge groups plays a critical role. In the more modern papers, finite generation of edge groups ensures that the group acts co-compactly on a nice square complex.

All this to say that a generalization of Swarup's Theorem to your situation may require to be some new ideas.